# PHP - Showing message after form submission using Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, magnific-popup

I have a form in a magnific popup. I want it in such a way that:

1.) After the user have submitted the form, a new magnific popup will open with a message showing that it has been submitted.

2.) If for example the user have already submitted the form, the magnific popup will show the message instead of the form to prevent multiple report being submitted.

So far I have the code below but its not showing the message.

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["btnSubmit"]))
{
    $issue = $_POST['issue'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, FROM report WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)
    {
        //Show message here
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO report (id, issue) VALUES ('$id', '$issue')");
    }
}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
<script>
function cancel(){
    $.magnificPopup.close();    
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.report').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: true,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    });

    $('#reportSubmittedContainer').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        fixedContentPos: true,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        overflowY: 'auto',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        preloader: false,
        midClick: true,
        mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#reportContainer" class="btnReport report" role="button">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Report
</a>

<div id="reportContainer" class="mfp-hide">
    <form class="form-horizontal submitReportForm" role="form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Issue:</label>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <textarea id="issue" name="issue" type="text" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="return validate();" class="btn btn-default" />
                <input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Cancel" onclick="return cancel();"class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div> 

<div id="reportSubmittedContainer" class="mfp-hide">
    We have received your report.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my comments :

> 1.) After the user have submitted the form, a new magnific popup will open with a message showing that it has been submitted.

Http is the protocol you are using currently. The Http   procedure is stateless , which means each request are unique . So when you submit form the DOM (document  object structure) is re-builded in server. 
In order to accomplish this kind of restrictions AJAX has been invented. 
I didn'y see the validate method on your  code . That may use AJAX but its not you should change.

> 2.) If for example the user have already submitted the form, the magnific popup will show the message instead of the form to prevent multiple report being submitted.

This is also the restrictions of HTTP protocol. Because of its stateless nature you have to use Cookies to send some information to client that indicates user has been submitted form previously. Both javascript and PHP has may send cookies.